# Compare 2 dynamic range columns in Excel VBA on a button push

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare 2 (B and C) columns and write in column D match or no match at a push of a button in Excel but I'm new to VBA.

Here is some of my noobie tries. I know it's not dynamic but I'm stuck and I can't figure this out. So bear with me. Any help is much appreciated

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim bothcolumns As Range, i As Integer


   Set bothcolumns = [B2:B3000, C2:C3000]
   With bothcolumns
    For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
    If Not StrComp(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
    With Value
           For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
        Range(.Cells(i, 5)).Value = "NoMatch"

        Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Range("E1:E300").Value = "NoMatch"
        ElseIf Not StrComp(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 2), vbBinaryCompare) = 1 Then
        Range("E1:E300").Value = "Match"
    End If

    Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your error ? Which line ? We need more information for help you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why is you error, but you have two loop for, and just one `Next i`. In addition your two loops have the same indent variable `i`.

Answer (score 0):

This will iterate over all the used rows in the worksheet, and then compare the cells value of the columns 'B' and 'C'.

Try this code:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim rowsMax As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'This gets the total of used rows in the Worksheet
    rowsMax = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = 2 To rowsMax
        If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value Then
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Match"
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = "No Match"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Some Tips:

1. `i` and `Value` are not declared. From my experience `i` should declare `As Long` and `Value` should declare `As Worskheet`
2. `With Value` and the second `For i = 1 To .Rows.Count` do not close with `Next i` and `End with` respectively.
3. For `i` is better to use `As Long` to avoid errors when you deal with large data size.
4. You use `.Cells` BUT you  dont use `.` before the `Range` so the range you what does not included in the upper `With`.
5. `bothcolumns` is declare `As Range`, BUT you use `[]`which is wrong. Also you set the range BUT you miss the Sheet name (e.g. `Set bothcolumns = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(...)`. In my opinion the best set is `Set bothcolumns = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:C3000")`